# call a server side Code on Anchor

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have the following code to download a file from a FTP server.

```
Sub DownloadFile_Sap()
        Dim remoteuri As String = "http://appsrv01.shakarganj.com.pk:7778/reports/rwservlet?reptest&report=sap_dashboard"
        Dim filename As String = Server.MapPath("~/Files/rwservlet_reptest&report=sap_dashboard.pdf")
        Dim mywebClient As New Net.WebClient()
        mywebClient.DownloadFile(remoteuri, filename)
    End Sub
```

Then call it on anchor tag like below:

```
<a   id="A1" href="http://202.125.144.34:83/Files/rwservlet_reptest&report=sap_dashboard.pdf" target=_blank   
      onmouseout="DownloadFile_Sap"  title="SAP"  runat="server">SAP</a>
```

But when I click the anchor it opens the link but does not download file from server.  What is the problem?  Can anyone please give me a solution for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you can avoid the double-click issue on the HREF by changing the HREF to a structure similar to the following:

```
<A HREF='#' onclick='return DownloadFile_SapClient()' title="SAP" runat="server">SAP</a>
```

If you return false from the onclick event, the URL will not be navigated to.

`DownloadFile_SapClient` is a javascript function that opens the requested URL in a new window:

```
function DownloadFile_SapClient()
{
    window.open('http://202.125.144.34:83/Files/rwservlet_reptest&report=sap_dashboard.pdf', '_blank');

    // Don't navigate to the hyperlink
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Sir U dnt get my question Correctly....Actualy sir i want to do that the file download progress should be on backend on browser console and on click or href the previous downloaded file should open so that the user dnt need to wait for downloading or opening file.The method u have tell i have already used in this way the user have to wait for file download.because i have a large amount of data on report to be downloaded please tell me another solution

Answer (score 0):

You can then make a jquery AJAX call to your method DownloadFile_Sap() (which willl be a web method), on mouse over to start download.

Comment: But i want to Call Servercode on mouse over instead of click because on click two events fire together href link get time to be executed and i want  to call href in one second and after opening href when mouse out the file start to download on backend

Comment: So can u please give me a bit example or piece of code to call my method on mouse event